# Measure Delta wound BLDC motor inductance and resistance

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, lcr, inductance-measurement

I'm using a VESC motor ESC to drive several different motors. When I connect a new motor, it has the ability to detect the motor parameters, but somehow gets it wrong for some of the larger motors: when I tried to run them afterward they would squeal or buck, and if I mess with the inductance and resistance values, the motor will start spinning on command, moreso the case under load. This has led me to try to read the values with an LCR meter.

I'm currently working with my BK Precision 891 LCR meter. But I'm not 100% certain that I'm measuring correctly. I'm an EE but I really don't dive this deep into motors, and several questions have come up:

- the motors are delta wound, so it's not as simple as reading the inductance and dividing by two, but more like a series - parallel configuration - how do I know what's correct?
- The motors still have their rotors on them, should they be removed for the test? does the presence of the rotor influence the magnetizing inductance?
- Do I need to take multiple readings with the rotor in multiple positions?
- Should I be looking for the DC resistance of the motor coil or the impedance?

Has anyone a good method of using an LCR meter to obtain the true inductance and resistance of the motor?